# R - dplyr merge in user-defined function

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a merge function as follows:

## Defined function

```
merge_tables <- function(inputdata1, inputdata2, byvar1, byvar2) {
  
byvar1 <- enquo(byvar1)
byvar2 <- enquo(byvar2)
  
  outputdata <- inputdata1 %>% 
    full_join(inputdata2, by = c(rlang::quo_text(byvar1) = rlang::quo_text(byvar2)))
  
  return(outputdata)
}
```

I am getting an error when I run using the following data and code:

## Mock data

```
set.seed(1)
data1<- data.frame(ID = sample(1:2), letter1 = sample(letters, 2, replace = TRUE))
data2<- data.frame(PatID = sample(1:3), letter2 = sample(letters, 3, replace = TRUE))
```

## Code using the defined function

```
testing_merge <- merge_tables(data1, data2, ID, PatID)
```

## Error message

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  outputdata <- inputdata1 %>% 
    full_join(inputdata2, by = c( (rlang::quo_text(byvar1)) ="
>   
>   return(outputdata)
Error: object 'outputdata' not found
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I wonder if anyone can see any glaring issues?... Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
merge_tables <- function(inputdata1, inputdata2, byvar1, byvar2) {

  byvar1 <- enquo(byvar1)
  byvar2 <- enquo(byvar2)

  by <- setNames(quo_name(byvar2), quo_name(byvar1))

  outputdata <- full_join(inputdata1, inputdata2, by = by)

  return(outputdata)

}
```

Returning:

```
testing_merge <- merge_tables(data1, data2, ID, PatID)

testing_merge

  ID letter1 letter2
1  1       o       r
2  2       x       q
3  3    <NA>       b
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: I have a question, is there a reason for the ordering of: setNames(quo_name(byvar2), quo_name(byvar1)). Should byvar1 not come first?

Comment: This is due to the nature of `setNames` where simply object comes first and naming later, i.e. `(object = nm)`. It can be confusing, but it is the right approach - I'm sure inversing them would throw you an error.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: this does not work me with
by <- setNames(quo_name(factor), quo_name(`AÑO`))