# Executing dplyr::left_join within a function using by=c(x=y) error

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function around dplyr::left_join, to simplify a repeated procedure I need to carry out multiple times.

Consider the following code:

```
    testdf <- data.frame(X1 = c("A", "B", "C"), X2 = c(1,2,3))

    testdf2 <- data.frame(Y1 = c("a", "b", "c"), Y2 = c(1,2,3))

    testdf3 <- dplyr::left_join(testdf, testdf2, by=c("X2" = "Y2"))
```

This approach works, as testdf3 will be a dataframe consisting of X1, X2 and Y1.
Now, consider the following function:

```
    test_function <- function(df1, df2, col1, col2){

        output_dataframe <- dplyr::join(df1, df2, by=(col1 = col2))

        return(output_dataframe)

    }

    output1 <- test_function(testdf, testdf2, "X2", "Y2")
```

This code throws me the following error:

"Error: `by` can't contain join column `col1` which is missing from LHS

It might be something minor as it seems to me it will not copy the column name variable into the left_join function properly, but I have been struggling with this problem for quite a while now.

I tried approaches such as the following:

```
    test_function <- function(df1, df2, col1, col2){

        helper <- c(col1 = col2)

        output_dataframe <- dplyr::join(df1, df2, by=helper)

        return(output_dataframe)

    }
```

However, the error is identical and I have no idea how to solve this.

I need this for a function which condenses several steps I need to execute repeatedly, executing the left_join within another function will therefore help me keep my code clean and readable. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you check out these answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101245/r-dplyr-merge-in-user-defined-function or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449799/join-datasets-using-a-quosure-as-the-by-argument

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find these at first. It seems that dplyr expects quoted arguments here, which can be supplied using the enquo() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This has something to do with evaluation, i think (see here:https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html)</s>  Maybe not...

I found a kind of hacky way, but it works for me:

```
test_function <- function(df1, df2, col1, col2){

   helper <- col2
   names(helper) <- col1

   output_dataframe <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by=helper)

   return(output_dataframe)

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This approach works indeed. I don't fully grasp why it won't work by assigning variables in the form of "by = c(X,Y)", but with this information I can continue my work.

Comment: Try `c(a=1)` and `c("a"=1)`, and look at the resulting output. You will see that it is the same and thats why c(col1=col2) does not work in the function call.